# PHP Register 3 Hashtags In Database Table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

hello here i have a string i want to register in database like this:
[image]

my code not work

```
function find_hashtags($string) {
        $hashtags = FALSE;  
        preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
        if ($matches) {
            $hashtags = implode(' , ', $matches[0]);
        }
        return $hashtags;
    }
$my_string = 'blabla #a ehehhe #b #c';
$find_hashtags = find_hashtags($my_string);
mysqli_query($Conn, "INSERT INTO `hashtags`(`post_id`, `hashtag`, `used`) VALUES ('$last_post_id', '$find_hashtags', '1')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1

Instead of creating a string in your `find_hashtag()` function, create an array.

```
function find_hashtags($string) {
        $hashtags = FALSE;  
        preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
        if ($matches) {
            $hashtags = implode(' , ', $matches[0]);
        }
        return explode(" ,", $hashtags);
    }
```

You now return an array.

## 2

Then loop through the array and `INSERT` every row of the array.

```
$my_string = 'blabla #a ehehhe #b #c';
$hashtags = find_hashtags($my_string);
foreach($hashtags as $hashtag) // Looping the array
{
    mysqli_query($Conn, "INSERT INTO `hashtags`(`post_id`, `hashtag`, `used`) VALUES ('$last_post_id', '$hashtag', '1')");
}
```

You may have to adapt this a bit but now, `$hashtags` is an array containning every hashtags of your string.

Please ask if something in unclear or if you need futher help.